# Printing a set which contains True

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Snippet:

```
for item in {1, 5.2, 10, 25, True}:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
1
10
5.2
25
```

Why is `True` not getting printed?

Comment: Because `1 == True`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But sets can contain heterogeneous data types, right? 1 is int whereas True is a bool.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak, try printing the set.

Comment: Sets test for equality when adding elements. It doesn't matter here that `boolean` is a subclass of `int`, types don't come into play.

Comment: Try creating the set with the elements reversed, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh I see, if I reverse the set then `True` gets printed but `1` doesn't. So it means that when the set gets created, it checks for duplicates and ignores the value if it finds the same value in existing set.

Comment: Yes, because sets only contain unique elements; you can't have two elements that test equal in the same set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 1 and `True` are same, so only one value exists since its a set. Regarding your comment, the set `{2, 2.0}` evaluates to be `set([2.0])`, despite their types are different.

Answer (score 2):

`True` and `1` is basically same value. So, only one will exist after set operation.